# addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() is not working

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Debugger shows the program gets into the loop but the list of albums is empty. 
I don't know why?

```
    d=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(ALBUMES);

    d.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //clearing the previous artist list
            albums.clear();
            //iterating through all the nodes
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //getting artist
                Album album = postSnapshot.getValue(Album.class);
                //adding artist to the list
                albums.add(album);
            }
            //creating adapter
            AlbumsLista albumAdapter = new AlbumsLista(getActivity(), albums);
            //attaching adapter to the listview
            listViewAlbums.setAdapter(albumAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "albums:"+ albums.size());
}
```

Comment: This might not solve your problem, but have in mind that [Firebase API functions are asynchronous](https://medium.com/@CodingDoug/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93), so you'll need to move the `albums.size()` log to your `onDataChange` method, right after the `for` loop.

Comment: in your reference you are doing wrong here .child(ALBUMES); , if ALBUMES is a string is ok, but you should name it "ALBUMES" for the reference

Comment: @GastónSaillén, the constant ALBUMES is a string

Comment: ok, now i have another question, you are doing albums.clear() after the datasnapshot, i mean, you can clear the album outside the method, and then do the database reference and add an album with your method, but im assuming you do it inside because you want to be sure that it fetches the new ones before clearing them., also , the Album.class is from any dependency or compile library or you did it by yourself ?